# Continuous sound listening and matching in background on Android

Tags: android, audio, signal-processing, android-background

I have a few sound files(not speech). I wish to run a service on an Android phone which continuously listen to the ambient sound and try to see if that sound matches with one of the sound files that I have. If a match is found I want to perform certain tasks.

I have multiple doubts here.

1. Is it even possible to do on Marshmallow and above devices with doze mode introduction?
2. Is there any third party library available to do such sound matching?

I have done some research but most of the questions on this topic are very old like [Android Speech Recognition as a service on Android 4.1 & 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940657/android-speech-recognition-as-a-service-on-android-4-1-4-2/14950616#14950616)
and [Wake up android phone with certain words like Hi Galaxy or Ok Google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19081074/wake-up-android-phone-with-certain-words-like-hi-galaxy-or-ok-google)